# How to convert a Piecewise function in a HeavisideTheta function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, piecewise, education, heat-equation

I want to convert a Piecewise function in a HeavisideTheta function in order to correctly evaluate its derivatives at the point of abrupt change and then integrate the result along the axis. How can I do that?
The function is given by:

````
xi=0.5;
yi=0.5;
f[x_,y_]:=Piecewise[{{1, 1-yi<=y<=1+yi&&1-xi<=x<=1+xi&&}}, 0.25]```

Thanks!
````

Comment: maybe ``g[x_, y_] := 
 Simplify`PWToUnitStep[f[x, y]] /. UnitStep -> HeavisideTheta // 
  FunctionExpand``?

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[g]

g[x_, y_] := FunctionExpand[Simplify`PWToUnitStep[f[x, y]] /. UnitStep -> HeavisideTheta]

g[x, y]
```

> ```
> 0.25 + 0.75 HeavisideTheta[1.5 - x, -0.5 + x, 1.5 - y, -0.5 + y]
> ```